# Customizing check-parens to check double-quotes

Tags: emacs

I have `check-parens` set to a save hook for my files, my Markdown files in particular, to alert me about unbalanced parentheses. They are almost always errors, and this has saved me from a great many errors involving Markdown links inside parenthetical asides:

```lisp
 ;In Markdown files, there are few excuses for unbalanced delimiters
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when buffer-file-name
              (add-hook 'after-save-hook
                        'check-parens
                        nil t))))
```

I've noticed that I have similar issues with quoting - I will drop a trailing quote, or I will forget to convert single and doubles appropriately, etc. (This sometimes overlaps with link errors when I put paper titles into the tooltip.) There's little more reason for imbalanced "s than there are for (s or )s, and it's the same task `check-parens` is already doing. So naturally I'd like to have `check-parens` cover quotes as well.

But I can't seem to do so! The right way seems to involve hacking the Markdown syntax table, but nothing I try seems to work –

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?\" "(\"" markdown-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?\" ")\"" markdown-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?\" "$\"" markdown-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?\" "^\"" markdown-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?\" ".\"" markdown-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?' "\"" markdown-mode-syntax-table)
```

etc etc etc. They all either do nothing or cause `check-parens` to spit out errors early in the file where as far as I can tell everything works just fine.

I've read through a number of links on the topic and the <kbd>C-h f</kbd> documentation for `modify-syntax-entry`:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParenthesisMatching#toc1
- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html
- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable
- http://zvon.org/other/elisp/Output/SEC561.html
- http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/elisp/elisp_32.html
- http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_350.html

and asked on `#emacs`, to no avail.

(The version is Emacs 24.0.93.1 on Debian unstable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?\" "\"" markdown-mode-syntax-table)
```

Comment: You know, I was about to say that that was one of the ones I had tried and found wanting - which it was - when it occurred to me I should check more carefully since an Emacser had suggested it. Turns out the test file was complicated enough I had missed an imbalanced quote pair. (Unfortunately, it seems the flashing-paren code which made it so easy to fix previous parentheses issues doesn't work for that, so I had to manually bisect the file until I figured out where the imbalance was.)